# Web2 friendly eCommerce frameworks for saas

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, e-commerce

Is there a payment and eCommerce framework which fits in a REST based application, out-of the-box ? My server runs with Java but the choices for this topic aren't that great. I don't mind to wrap my interface to something else.

In my application the user should able to aquire new services on subscripton base with a single click. Most frameworks are not very AJAX friendly, thats why I am asking. Possibly there is also just a simple JS or JAVA for the payment gateways itself.

Thanks a lot

Comment: [spreecommerce](http://spreecommerce.com/) sounds good

Comment: Sounds only good but fails in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Broadleaf Commerce](http://broadleafcommerce.org) which is built using latest technologies (Spring, Apache Solr, jQuery, Thymeleaf) and has JAX-RS Rest API support.

Comment: thanks, that was the first I tried I did end up to write on own.